# Electron webPreferneces scrollBounce ineffective

Tags: object, scroll, electron

The documentation for Electron states that the native macOS bounce effect on scrolling can be implemented using the webPreferences object when initating the browser window.

```
win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      scrollBounce: true
    }
  })
```

This does not appear to have any effect when tested in 1.3.5. The documentation is clear at https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md

Is this a bug or have we missed something.

Comment: maybe this can help you : https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/5412

Comment: @MaximeF Unfortunately they appear to have the same problem